# IBMQ.load_account from stored ACCOUNT is failing on Qiskit 0.9.0

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

The following statement is causing an error in Qiskit Version 0.9.0:

```
provider = IBMQ.load_account()
```

Error Message:

```
IBMQAccountError: 'IBM Q Experience v1 credentials found. Please update your accounts and programs by following the instructions here:\nhttps://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibmq-provider#updating-to-the-new-ibm-q-experience'
```

The display of the account finformation from the stored location is working OK and matches the API key:

```
print(str(IBMQ.stored_account())) 

{'token': '94....051', 'url': 'https://auth.quantum-computing.ibm.com/api'}
```

When using the provider = IBMQ.load_account("94....051"), the authentication  completed normally. I've already tried to manually delete the registry with rm ~/.qiskit/qiskitrc, or by using the IBMQ.delete_account() command, or by doing the IBMQ.update_account(), as well as doing a refresh of the token. The error persist at the the load_account() function.

Versions used:

```
0.9.0
{'qiskit-terra': '0.9.0', 'qiskit-ignis': '0.2.0', 'qiskit-aqua': '0.6.0', 'qiskit': '0.12.0', 'qiskit-aer': '0.3.0', 'qiskit-ibmq-provider': '0.3.2'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and answer. Indeed, the overwrite flag on the save_account command solved the issue together with an update of the API key. Possibly the error was part of my release upgrade process, or some "cached" class in Anaconda. Its solved and the authentication is working now.

Comment: Hi try the I suggested in this, worked for me.
https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9651/ibmqfactory-object-has-no-attribute-load-accounts/9652#9652

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error means that old credentials are still in use on your disk. Try getting a new API key from [the website](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/) and then running `IBMQ.save_account('APIKEY', overwrite=True)`. This should overwrite the existing old credentials with new ones.