# 'IBMQFactory' object has no attribute 'load_accounts'

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices

I am following this qiskit workshop from https://colab.research.google.com/github/mtreinish/qiskit-workshop/blob/master/Workshop.ipynb . After adding my API key I had encountered the error `'IBMQFactory' object has no attribute 'load_accounts'`  when running `qiskit.IBMQ.load_accounts()`.  **How do I fix this?**

Answer (score 4):

IBMQ.load_accounts() was deprecated and removed in Qiskit 0.14. Please use IBMQ.load_account().

Answer (score 1):

I also came across with the same issue. However when I added my account token as follows, it worked.

```
token = 'Your token'
IBMQ.save_account(token)    
provider = IBMQ.load_account()
device = provider.get_backend('ibmq_16_melbourne')
```

You can get your IBM Q token via : https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/account

Hope this helped, let me know if it didn't.